# Visual Studio 2019: Cannot get rid of warning on VC++ 2015 runtime not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, redistributable

I have Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition, with a UWP project.
At some point in time, a new reference appeared in my project, Visual C++ 2015 redistributables., with a warning when I compile, which says

> The referenced component 'Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal
>   Windows Platform Apps' could not be found

I tried to remove the reference by right click => remove, but when I close and reopen the project, it re-appears.
Such reference, moreover, seems not to be saved in the .csproj, nor in other solution files.

I tried to download the redistributables as specified here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eab6ac56-44c7-416e-8397-d062baed987c/uwpc-i-got-issues-when-i-was-trying-to-release-my-app?forum=wpdevelop but when I try to install it says I already have a newer version.

How can I get rid of this warning / reference?

Answer (score 2):

To get this to go away I had to do two steps:

1. Install the C++ (v142) Universal Windows Platform tools under Optional components in the Visual Studio installers Workload modifier (or whatever is the latest by the time you are reading this answer.)

[image]

2. In your project under Reference Manager > Universal Windows > Extensions un-check Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform.  When I closed the dialog, it did not remove the reference but it did fix it.  I was expecting to have to re-add the reference but I did not, it was still there.

[image]